# In Ruby, what's the best way to execute a block around a child method?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I have a parent class:

```
class Base
  def my_method
    block_method do
      # EXECUTE WHATEVER'S IN THE CHILD VERSION OF my_method
      # HOW TO DO?
    end
  end

  def block_method
    original_foo = 'foo'
    foo = 'CUSTOM FOO'

    yield

    foo = original_foo
  end
end
```

and some child classes--currently five and there will be more:

```
class ChildA < Base
  def my_method
    puts 'apple'
    puts 'aardvark'
  end
end

class ChildE < Base
  def my_method
    puts 'eel'
    puts 'elephant'
  end
end
```

I want to change what a variable refers to just for the duration of each `Child`'s `#my_method`.

My thought is to do this by wrapping the functionality of each `Child`'s `#my_method` in a block. But I'd rather do that in the parent class than have to wrap each child class's `#my_method` in the exact same block.

Any insights on how I can do this?

If there's some opposite of `super`, I guess that would be one way to accomplish what I want to do.

Comment: I suggest you edit to give an example of what you want `ChildA#my_method` to return.

Comment: It seems that you want each child's `my_method` to simply execute the method `Base#my_method` and then execute something else (`puts` statements in the example). If so, for `ChildA`, simply `def my_method; super; puts "apple"; puts "aardvark"; end`, and the fact that `Base#my_method` calls some other method with a block is irrelevant.  Note that `"Aardvark"` usually comes first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could give the idea of what you are calling "some opposite of super" using a module and `prepend` like so:

```
module MethodThing
  # added to remove binding from class since 
  # #my_method relies on the existence of #foo and #foo=
  def self.prepended(base)
    base.attr_reader(:foo) unless base.method_defined?(:foo)
    base.attr_writer(:foo) unless base.method_defined?(:foo=)
  end
  def my_method
    puts "Before: #{foo}"
    original_foo = foo
    self.foo= 'CUSTOM FOO'
    begin
      super
    rescue NoMethodError
      warn "(skipped) #{self.class}##{__method__} not defined"
    end
    self.foo = original_foo
    puts "After: #{foo}"
  end
end
```

Prepend the module on inheritance

```
class Base 
  def self.inherited(child)
    child.prepend(MethodThing)
  end

  attr_accessor :foo 
  def initialize
    @foo = 12
  end
end


class ChildA < Base
  def my_method
      puts 'apple'
      puts "During: #{foo}"
      puts 'aardvark'
  end
end

class ChildE < Base
end
```

Output:

```
ChildA.new.my_method
# Before: 12
# apple
# During: CUSTOM FOO
# aardvark
# After: 12
ChildE.new.my_method
# Before: 12
# (skipped) ChildE#my_method not defined
# After: 12
```

There are other strange ways to accomplish this with inheritance as well such as

```
class Base
 class << self
   attr_accessor :delegate_my_method
   def method_added(method_name)
     if method_name.to_s == "my_method" && self.name != "Base"
       warn "#{self.name}#my_method has been overwritten use delegate_my_method instead" 
     end
   end
 end
 attr_accessor :foo       

 def my_method
   puts "Before: #{foo}"
    original_foo = foo
    self.foo= 'CUSTOM FOO'
    begin
      method(self.class.delegate_my_method.to_s).()
    rescue NameError, TypeError
      warn "(skipped) #{self.class} method delegation not defined"
    end
    self.foo = original_foo
    puts "After: #{foo}"
 end
end

class ChildA < Base
  self.delegate_my_method = :delegation_method

  def delegation_method
    puts 'apple'
    puts "During: #{foo}"
    puts 'aardvark'
  end
end
```

I could probably keep going with stranger and stranger ways to solve this problem but I think these will get you where you need to go.

Comment: I've used this answer as inspiration (thanks) but realized that `inherited` will be called multiple times if there are multiple inheritance levels.
To not call `prepend` multiple times I ended up safeguarding it with `if name == Base.to_s`

Comment: @NBcrafts not sure I understand. The purpose is to wrap an existing method if it exists. If `class X < E` defines `my_method`  then the wrapping will be skipped under your implementation. Is that your desired intent? Additionally if my answer assisted you in some fashion please feel free to upvote. 

Comment: My experience with it is that with `class ChildX < ChildA`, the `.inherited` method in `Base` will be called twice (once for each level of inheritance) and apply the wrapper twice. (And with your example see `Before: 12` twice).
`.inherited` is being called on the parent class, so with my change, the first time it will apply the wrapper because that parent is `Base`, but the second time it won't because the parent will be `ChildA`.

Comment: Also, I'm realizing this probably happens to me because rubocop made me add `super` in my `.inherited` method to not break higher inheritance logic.
EDIT: Nope, nevermind, happens without `super` as well.

Comment: @NBcrafts that's fair enough thank you for the clarification. Additionally then the second proposal would work better as it does not inject anything into the inheritance chain. There are other options as well like creating a `Method` object from the original implementation and calling it as a block

Comment: All good, just sharing my findings, this solution is working great for me (thanks again), just needed that extra safeguard for my usage.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to define a private or nodoc method which the parent class can call and is defined in each of the children.

```
class Parent
  def my_method
    block_method do
      my_method_behavior
    end
  end

  def block_method
    original_foo = @foo
    @foo = 'CUSTOM FOO'

    yield

    @foo = original_foo
  end
end

class Child1 < Parent
  def my_method_behavior
    puts @foo
  end
end

class Child2 < Parent
  def my_method_behavior
    puts @foo
  end
end
```

Comment: `private_my_method` is perhaps not a good name for a public method. :-)